# Twitter-client-like NSCollectionView implementation on OS X (>=10.6)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, binding, nscollectionview

I'm trying to subclass a NSCollectionView which imitate the behaviors of UITableView as [Twitter](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitter/id409789998?mt=12) does.

I've been trying to subclass/hack [AMCollectionView](http://www.harmless.de/cocoa-code.php), which “has a lot less features.”
AMCollectionView used an immutable array to populate data into items, however, what I visioned is a twitter like table/list, whose data arrays is mutable, and it should support insertion and removal like UITableView does.

BTW, I'm still struggling with Key-Value Binding stuff. Any suggestion/solution/example code for NSCollectionView are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter released their [twui libs](https://github.com/twitter/twui).